# .NET (Data Import )

Tags: c#

I have a urgent question?

For Data import from Source Excel to SQL Server Which is going to be one time import.
which is the best way to do it .NET

Comment: SQL Management Studio -> Right click your database -> Tasks -> Import Data...

Comment: Need some more information please. You have tagged this as C#, does this mean you want to do it using C#? Does the data map to any specific objects/database tables? Have you tried the import wizard in SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that you may find [helpful](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2976.aspx).

Basically you access the file somewhat like you would a database. Some trial and error involved, but overall not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. For a simple one time import, just copy paste from excel straight into the management studio row editing screen.  i.e. skip .Net entirely.
2. For a little more complicated, use management studio, right click on the database and say "import data"...
3. If it really must be a .net app, use ADO to open the excel file, read the records and write them to your SQL server.